# call a java properties class

Tags: java, properties

Need to create a class that i can load properties in and be able to call required properties from that class. such as propertiesClass.getname();

Here's my Class so far. I can't seem to initiate the property load.

So what i need is from another class in the project to just do (currently getting null)

String url = TestProperties.getBaseUrl();

*updated the class, here's what it looks like now.

```
    public class TestProperties {

    private static Properties testProperties;
    private static String instanceUrl;

    public TestProperties() throws Exception{

         loadProperties();
         getInstanceProperties();
         instanceUrl =  TestProperties.testProperties.getProperty("confluence.base.url","");
    }

    public static String getBaseUrl(){

          return instanceUrl;
    }


    private void loadProperties() throws IOException {
        InputStream testPropertiesInput = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("smoketest.properties");
        TestProperties.testProperties = new Properties();

//        if (null != testProperties) {
            try{
                TestProperties.testProperties.load(testPropertiesInput);
            } finally {
                IOUtils.closeQuietly(testPropertiesInput);
            }
//        }
     }

}


my otherclass(){
 String myurl = TestProperties.getBaseUrl();
}
```

Comment: You're making your life too complicated there. The easy way to load `.properties` files is `ResourceBundle.getBundle(...)`. See the [`ResourceBundle` docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html).

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are able to rightly access your properties file `smoketest.properties` though `InputStream testPropertiesInput`.

EDIT:

There is no need to redefine the local variable in `loadProperties` and return it. It can be written very simply as:

```
   private static void loadProperties() throws IOException {
       InputStream testPropertiesInput = getClass().getClassLoader()
                                     .getResourceAsStream("smoketest.properties");
       Properties testProperties = new Properties();
       try{
            TestProperties.testProperties.load(testPropertiesInput);
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(testPropertiesInput);
        }
        TestProperties.testProperties = testProperties;
    }
```

**I think `public void TestProperties() throws Exception{` is constructor of your class. If yes, please remove `void` from it as it making it as a method.**

Finally you may want to use `testProperties` in your `TestProperties()` constructor as :

```
 public TestProperties() throws Exception{
     loadProperties();
     getInstanceProperties();
     instanceUrl = TestProperties.testProperties
                                            .getProperty("confluence.base.url","");
  }
```

**Please Note: I don't think your class variables should be defined as `static`. Is there any reason of doing so?**

**EDIT: Here is the hopefully working sample code for you:**

```
    public class TestProperties {

        private static Properties testProperties;
        private static String instanceUrl;

        public TestProperties(){
            try{
                loadProperties();
                //getInstanceProperties();
                instanceUrl = TestProperties.testProperties
                                        .getProperty("confluence.base.url","");
               }catch(IOException ioe){
                 ioe.printStackTrace();
               }
        }

        static{
             //Just to initialize the properties
             new TestProperties();
        }        

        private void loadProperties() throws IOException {
          InputStream testPropertiesInput = getClass().getClassLoader()
                                .getResourceAsStream("smoketest.properties");
          Properties testProperties = new Properties();
          try{
              testProperties.load(testPropertiesInput);
          } finally {
               IOUtils.closeQuietly(testPropertiesInput);
          }
          TestProperties.testProperties = testProperties;
        }

        public static String getBaseUrl(){
              return instanceUrl;
        }

        public static String getPropertyValue(String key){
              return TestProperties.testProperties.getProperty(key,"Not Found");
        }
    }
```

Now you can simply get your base URL any where as :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(TestProperties.getBaseUrl());
        System.out.println(TestProperties.getPropertyValue("confluence.base.url"));
        System.out.println(TestProperties.getPropertyValue("test.property"));
    }
```

Comment: He is redefining `testProperties` but he's returning them as well. Shadowing the field was probably intended

Comment: @JanDvorak: I noticed, its returning the `testProperties`. Removed that part from the answer already. I think its file accessing probelm from classPath.

Comment: ah crap, can you put your previous answer, the inputstream is fine.

Comment: @user979587: Restored the answer with little additional details. Please check and let me know, if this doesn't help.

Comment: @YogendraSingh not assigning early is a good idea if the loading may fail, so you leave the class with `null`s instead of broken objects. In this case, he is creating a new `Properties` object and then manipulating it.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Updated the answer to work with local instance then assign it to static variable in the end. Though I really don't know, why it has to be static.

Comment: I believe `TestProperties.testProperties = testProperties;` is a syntax error if `testProperties` is not static (which it shouldn't be).

Comment: I'm getting missing return statement from your above loadPRoperties method. could someone write up a properties class that can be called from other classes.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Ooops... I intended to update it to Properties :(

Comment: @JanDvorak: It is private method.

Comment: actually its fine. i forgot to update it to void. so how do i call the instanceURl variable from another class? or do i make a getter method?

Comment: @user979587: Is it working now? Static variable need depends on your usage pattern. Please note that uou need to call the constructor at least once before getting the `instanceURl` value.

Comment: nope, just hits the getBaseUrl() methods and does not seem to instantiate the TestPRoperties() constructor

Comment: @user979587: How are you calling? Are you directly calling `getBaseUrl()` without calling the constructor?

Comment: in another class String myurl = TestProperties.getBaseUrl();

Comment: @user979587: This is what I was suspecting from beginning. Please remember, you have put the initialization code in the constructor, which you are not calling at all. Please refer my updated answer(bottom section) for one way out(using static initialization block).

Comment: @user979587 I posted a hopefully FULL working sample code in the answer. Please check.

Comment: Thanks Yogendra, i will give it a go, but how can i come up with a solution for 20 property variables? i have a method that sets 20 variables to system properties, should i make this class an abstract class and extend the other class?

Comment: @user979587 Why do you want to create getter methods for all your properties? Create one generic one, which will accept the `key` as parameter e.g. `public static String getPropertyValue(String key){...}`, inside this method, do a look-up and return the value.

Comment: @user979587: There was a slight issue in `InputStream` loading due to static class reference. Also added `getPropertyValue` as suggested earlier. This time, I validated my self and it is working fine. Please check the updated code.

Comment: @YogendraSingh At that point you might as well use `ResourceBundle.getBundle(...).getString(...)` directly, making this class unnecessary. Which is workable, but having your configuration properties clearly enumerated makes things easier to understand, and prevents typos for the various configuration keys.

Answer (score 0):

The method

```
public void TestProperties() throws Exception{
```

was meant to be constructor but isn't one, so the class only gets a default no-arg constructor. Change that to:

```
public TestProperties() throws Exception{
```

i.e. remove the return type as constructors are distinguished from ordinary methods by not declaring a return type.

Comment: when i do this from another class and debug: String myurl = TestProperties.getBaseUrl(); i'm still getting null

Comment: @user979587 well, at least your constructor gets called now. I suggest tracing the code starting at the constructor. I will keep looking at your source code in the mean time ;-)

Comment: its like it hit the method getBaseUrl(); , but the actual properties are not being instantiated? how can i do this?

Comment: @user979587 so 1) you create a new `TestObject` that 2) doesn't throw any exception and then 3) you call its method and 4) it's not giving the expected results? Then I suggest you set up a break point inside the constructor to see what happens during the construction.